# VBA to loop through to check if datetime is between 2 datetime cells on another worksheet

Tags: vba, loops

I have worksheetA with userid, resettime and hit(Y/N)

I have worksheetB with userid and starttime, endtime - (userid can have multiple starttime,endtimes)

e.g.

```
UserID      starttime           endtime
AJones      4/10/2021 11:00am   4/10/2021  12:00pm
AJones      4/10/2021 2:00pm    4/10/2021  2:30pm
```

I need to loop through the userids on worksheetB based on the UserID match - so if the userid from worksheetA=userid from worksheetB, then check to see if the resettime in worksheet A is between the starttime and endtime on worksheet B.  If it hits a row where it is in between, then fill in column called hit as "Y" else "N" and move on to the next userid.

Comment: You can use COUNTIFS() for this

Comment: Ahhh - thanks - I'll try that:)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this.  Here's an example using COUNTIFS():

[image]